# Syntax error in python while executing

Tags: python-2.7

```
import random
print "I can sense your mood through your touches on keyboard"
print "you are .........."
mood=random.range(3)
if mood==0:
    print \
          """ 
        |---------------|               
        |               |
        |  0       0    |
        |               |
        |     <         |
        | -          -  |
        |  -       -    |
        |    - - -      |
        |---------------|
        """:
elif mood==1:
    print"your mood is"
    print \ """  
        |==============|              |
        |   0     0    |
        |              | 
        |  ----------  |
        |              |
        |==============|
        neutral """:
elif mood==2:
    print" u r sad dear"
    print \
          """ 
        |===============|               
        |   0     0     |
        |               |
        |    - - -      |
        |  -       -    |
        | -          -  | 
        |===============|               

             """
else:
    print " u r really in a bad mood"
print " today..........."
raw_input ("\n\n\npress enter to exit")
```

no idea why it shows syntax error

Comment: If you look at your console it actually tells you exactly where the error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't end print statements with colons.  One colon after the word neutral

`neutral """:`

(there's another one up on line 17)

You also can't have

`print \ """`

Because `\` is line continuation character, you shouldn't have any characters after that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

remove `:` after **print**

use `randrange()` to replace `range()`

```
import random
print "i can sence your mood through your touches on keyboard"
print "you are .........."
mood=random.randrange(3)
if mood==0:
    print \
          """ 
        |---------------|               
        |               |
        |  0       0    |
        |               |
        |     <         |
        | -          -  |
        |  -       -    |
        |    - - -      |
        |---------------|
        """
elif mood==1:
    print"your mood is"
    print \
          """
        |==============|              |
        |   0     0    |
        |              | 
        |  ----------  |
        |              |
        |==============|
        neutral """
elif mood==2:
    print" u r sad dear"
    print \
          """ 
        |===============|               
        |   0     0     |
        |               |
        |    - - -      |
        |  -       -    |
        | -          -  | 
        |===============|               

             """
else:
    print " u r really in a bad mood"
print " today..........."
raw_input ("\n\n\npress enter to exit")
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what changes you made and why?

Comment: remove : after print
have a no range() method of random  then i replace 
use randrange() to replace range()

Comment: Why replace the rand?

Comment: hi friends random  is not provide range() method 
& i remove ':' in print syntext

Comment: if see all method of then go in terminal and type python & import random then after dir(random)